# Rogue task running on Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've dropped a task and replaced it with a new one in Snowflake, except the old one appears to continue running even when it is not in SHOW TASKS.

Original task creation:

```
CREATE TASK MY_OLD_TASK
WAREHOUSE=MY_WAREHOUSE
SCHEDULE='USING CRON 0 5,17 * * * UTC'
AS
insert overwrite into "MY_SCHEMA".MY_TABLE(MY_FIELDS)
SELECT MY_OLD_SQL
```

```
ALTER TASK MY_OLD_TASK RESUME
```

Removing the old task and updating it with the new task:

```
DROP TASK MY_OLD_TASK
```

```
CREATE TASK MY_NEW_TASK
WAREHOUSE=MY_WAREHOUSE
SCHEDULE='USING CRON 0 5,17 * * * UTC'
AS
insert overwrite into "MY_SCHEMA".MY_TABLE(MY_FIELDS)
SELECT MY_NEW_SQL
```

```
ALTER TASK MY_NEW_TASK RESUME
```

If I take the current definition field of my new task and run it from my SHOW TASKS result, it populates my table with what I want it to. I went audited my two other tasks that exist and made sure they weren't writing to this table as well.

```
SHOW TASKS
```

```
created_on|name|definition
2021-04-14 18:12:25.283-0700|my_other_task1|(definition not affecting MY_TABLE)
2021-04-16 16:13:15.285-0300|my_other_task2|(definition not affecting MY_TABLE)
2021-04-16 16:13:15.285-0300|MY_NEW_TASK|(definition that does exactly what I want it to on MY_TABLE)
```

The first time this happened I figured the old task was running still when I dropped the old task and replaced it with the new. Except now it has happened for the second day in a row.

Why is there an older task running that doesn't appear in show tasks and how do I stop it? Desired result is only to have MY_NEW_TASK run with the current definition I see corresponding to it in show tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old one is **probably** in different schema than active one. You could search all tasks using:

```
SHOW TASKS IN DATABASE;
```

And then drop it:

```
DROP TASK IF EXISTS <schema_name>.<old_task_name>;
```

Comment: That was it! Except the show tasks in database command doesn't work for me saying SQL compilation error: Schema 'MY_DB.MY_DB' does not exist or not authorized, if you have any suggestions there. It only works using SHOW TASKS IN MY_DB."MY_SCHEMA" or SHOW TASKS IN MY_DB."MY_ALT_SCHEMA", I don't know the command to always see all tasks.

Comment: @MarkMcGown `SHOW .. IN DATABASE` should show tasks in schemas you have access to. It is strange if it error out. Right now I have no way to reproduce it, but feel free to report it to SF support.